# How can I put an async function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This is the code I'm using. It doesn't work because client.getPosts is async. So my question is, how can I make it work? client.getPosts is from the wordpress npm module so I cannot change it.

```
// FUNCTIONS

function getAllPosts() {
    return client
        .getPosts( {type: 'post', status : 'publish', number : 222} , ['title','id'] , (error, posts) => {
        return posts
            .map((item) => {
            return item.title
            })
        })
}


// MAIN

console.log(getAllPosts());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I sugest you using lamba functions so you can do:
    somFunction = () => client.getPost(config)
and then using promises when calling the function

Comment: @arracso any way you could write me literally what I need to write? I've been trying to understand promises for a long time but still dont understand how to use them, especially in this context where I'm using a module.

Comment: promises is just a function that executes with the result of another function. I don't know how getPosts works, but if it works like an ajax requests then instead of passing a function to getPosts you can use a promise, in ajax:
`$.ajax(/*config*/).done(/*here do whatever you whant woth the response*/)´ or you can use other promises like `.fail()`, `.then()`, `.error()`.. So the best option can be to have the function with his configuration of getPost and name it just like i done. Then you may use the function with the promises. (I cannot explain me better I new to promises to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the callback function to  `getAllPosts`.

```
getAllPosts(cb){
return client
    .getPosts( {type: 'post', status : 'publish', number : 222} , ['title','id'] , (error, posts) => {
    cb(posts
        .map((item) => {
        return item.title
        }))
    })
}

getAllPosts(function(posts){
   console.log(posts)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I don't really understand it though. In what order are things happening?

Comment: You're welcome.
When you call the `getAllPosts`  it  calls to async `getPosts` function and when the result comes from the server the callback function for `getPosts` fires :
`.getPosts({something}, (err, posts)=>{})`
The `(err, posts)=>{}` is the callback function for `.getPosts`, in which we'll call to OUR callback function `cb` and pass the result to it.

For good understanding please read this [link](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

in .getPosts() method you are using 3 params an object an array and a function referance.

The point is you are sending a referance to that function. You should execute that functon after your process end. but your code line won't wait youır process end.

Comment: I'm returning client.getPosts, isn't that the same thing as executing?

Comment: your process is still running when you return your value in higher function. theres nothing to return.

Comment: do not think single timeline. theres multi time lines in javascript if you create processes